# Four riddles from a video game

Tags: riddle

I recently played this game, [Fran Bow](http://www.franbow.com/). This is a puzzle game, and thus has a lot of riddles.

But here are the four that I favor among all. I am four different things. Who or what am I?

[image]

> 1. I'm cold as I am, but if you use me... I'll be burning hard.
> 2. I'm shiny as the sun but I'll never burn you. Perhaps a sour smile I'll get you.
> 3. Flow, flow cold blooded son. Let your body dance through the rising stream.
> 4. Light and hollow, I'm the freedom of birds and the pen of men.

Note that in each question, I am different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, 4 is clearly

> FEATHER: it's light with a hollow shaft, gives birds their freedom in the sky, and was used in old-style pens.

3 must be

> FISH (shades of Gollum in this one): it's cold-blooded and dances through flowing streams.

2 is probably

> LEMON: it's yellow like the sun, makes you grimace with its sourness, but doesn't burn you.

And 1 sounds like

> a MATCH: it's cold before being used, but then instantly flares up when struck.

Comment: I just signed up to answer this. But couldn't figure out the 4th, was thinking something else for it, your answer makes more sense :) +1.  The other 3 were same as my guesses

Comment: @Doomsknight The 4th was the first one to click for me (which is why this answer is in reverse order). But if you have an alternative which also makes sense, do post another answer! :-)

Comment: It didn't fit the pen bit. Hence i was still trying to figure it out when i saw your answer :)

Comment: Clearly, you're a professional riddle solver :) All of them are true! And for the ones who liked this riddle, the game is a strong suggestion.

Comment: For #2 I thought of the Moon.  It shines, it doesn't burn like the Sun and it can give a smile in the form of a crescent.